# MySQL: Column count doesn't match value count at row 3

Tags: mysql

When I run my code I get the Error "Column count doesn't match value count at row 3" The only answer I was seeing was that one of my sections had to many or to little columns. I went through my tables and insert code and they match up with the amount. I have tried a few other things but nothing seems to fix it. Not sure what the issue is. Thanks for any advice or help! (Hopefully I am not just being a fool and missing something simple.)

```
CREATE TABLE Restaurant
  (Rest_id integer NOT NULL,
  Rest_phone integer NOT NULL,
  Rest_name VARCHAR(255),
  Rest_street VARCHAR(255),
  Rest_city VARCHAR(255),
  Rest_state VARCHAR(255),
  Rest_zip integer NOT NULL,
  Rest_Pmtid integer NOT NULL,
  Rest_cuisine VARCHAR(255),
  CONSTRAINT Restaurant_PK PRIMARY KEY (Rest_id));


CREATE TABLE Customer
  (Cust_id integer NOT NULL,
  Cust_phone integer NOT NULL,
  Cust_fname VARCHAR(255),
  Cust_lname VARCHAR(255),
  Cust_street VARCHAR(255),
  Cust_city VARCHAR(255),
  Cust_state VARCHAR(255),
  Cust_zip integer NOT NULL,
  Cust_Pmtid integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT Customer_PK PRIMARY KEY (Cust_id));


CREATE TABLE Driver
  (Driver_id integer NOT NULL,
  Driver_phone integer NOT NULL,
  Driver_fname VARCHAR(255),
  Driver_lname VARCHAR(255),
  Driver_license VARCHAR(255),
  Driver_plate VARCHAR(255),
  Driver_status VARCHAR(255),
  Driver_Pmtid integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT Driver_PK PRIMARY KEY (Driver_id));


CREATE TABLE Grub_Order
  (Rest_id integer NOT NULL,
  Cust_id integer NOT NULL,
  Order_time DATETIME,
  Order_id integer NOT NULL,
  Order_status VARCHAR(255),
  Driver_id integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT Grub_Order_PK PRIMARY KEY (Rest_id, Cust_id, Driver_id),
  CONSTRAINT Grub_Restaurant_FK FOREIGN KEY(Rest_id) REFERENCES Restaurant(Rest_id),
  CONSTRAINT Grub_Customer_FK FOREIGN KEY(Cust_id) REFERENCES Customer(Cust_id),
  CONSTRAINT Grub_Driver_FK FOREIGN KEY(Driver_id) REFERENCES Driver(Driver_id));

INSERT INTO Restaurant(Rest_id, Rest_phone, Rest_name, Rest_street, Rest_city, Rest_state, Rest_zip, Rest_Pmtid, Rest_cuisine)
VALUES(1, 6788931568, "Paunch Burger", "6872 Lard Lane", "Pawnee", "IN", 46011, 4826, "Fast Food"),
  (2, 4569873185, "JJ's Diner", "23428 Main St,", "Pawnee", "IN", 46011, 78623, "Breakfast"),
  (3, 7862354862, "Mulligans", "6876 Classy Rd.", "Indianapolis", "IN", 46077, "Steakhouse");


INSERT INTO Customer(Cust_id, Cust_phone, Cust_fname, Cust_lname, Cust_street, Cust_city, Cust_state, Cust_zip, Cust_Pmtid)
VALUES(1, 4025534397, "April", "Ludgate", "123 S 55 Ave.", "Omaha", "NE", 68132, 23456),
  (2, 2344325437, "Leslie", "Knope", "4387 Waffle Drive", "Pawnee", "IN", 46011, 98754),
  (3, 4569873265, "Ron", "Swanson", "987 Bacon Avenue", "Pawnee", "IN", 46011, 234789),
  (4, 0000000000, "Andy", "Dwyer", "2468 The Pit", "Pawnee", "IN", 46011, 12390);


INSERT INTO Driver(Driver_id, Driver_phone, Driver_fname, Driver_lname, Driver_license, Driver_plate, Driver_status, Driver_Pmtid)
VALUES(1, 2869372250, "Henry", "Roth", "C04790049", "IUC989", "Active", 444862),
  (2, 8156050336, "Charity", "Osborne", "D89973937", "REW222", "Active", 959227),
  (3, 9438936193, "Fritz", "Macias", "U06119817", "XUA177", "Active", 718371),
  (4, 5132849064, "Brenden", "Hill", "X22173227", "IOL455", "Active", 334452),
  (5, 9094778843, "Leah", "Peters", "V44276914", "AJA879", "Inactive", 603268);


INSERT INTO Grub_Order(Rest_id, Cust_id, Order_time, Order_id, Order_status, Driver_id)
VALUES(1, 1, "2020-09-30 6:44:00", 1, "out", 1),
  (1, 1, "2020-09-30 10:44:00", 2, "placed", 2),
  (2, 2, "2020-09-30 10:54:00", 3, "fulfilled", 3),
  (3, 3, "2020-09-30 10:46:00", 4, "placed", 4),
  (2, 4, "2020-09-30 11:44:00", 5, "cancelled", 1);
```

Comment: Please check the third row in the insert statement to the table restaurant, you're missing one value for the column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a field for Restaurant #3.

```
INSERT INTO Restaurant(Rest_id, Rest_phone, Rest_name, Rest_street, Rest_city, Rest_state, Rest_zip, Rest_Pmtid, Rest_cuisine) VALUES (
    3,  -- Rest_id
    7862354862,  -- Rest_phone
    "Mulligans",  -- Rest_name
    "6876 Classy Rd.",  -- Rest_street
    "Indianapolis",  -- Rest_city
    "IN",  -- Rest_state
    46077,  -- Rest_zip
    -- Rest_Pmtid ???
    "Steakhouse". -- Rest_cuisine
);
```